# Api test runtime error with specific endpoint

Tags: api, go, testing, web-api-testing, gorilla

I use gorilla/mux and I developed my API with hexagonal architecture. I want to test all layers via API test. I wrote a simple test to get an idea of is working or not. While the test gives a runtime error with the correct URL path, it does not give an error when I give an unused path.

```
> === RUN   TestGenerateDeepLink
> --- FAIL: TestGenerateDeepLink (0.00s) panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]    panic: runtime
> error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal
> SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x10220f584]
> 
> goroutine 4 [running]: testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x1022a7040,
> 0x102430430})     /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1209 +0x258
> testing.tRunner.func1(0x14000117860)
```

My test:

```
package api

import (
    "bytes"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "loremipsum/pkg/repository/link"
    "loremipsum/pkg/service"
)

func dbSetup() (*sql.DB, sqlmock.Sqlmock) {
    db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()
    return db, mock
}

func routersSetup(api ConverterAPI) *mux.Router {
    apiRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    apiRouter.HandleFunc("/getDeepLink", api.GenerateDeepLink()).Methods("POST")
    return apiRouter
}

func apiSetup(db *sql.DB) ConverterAPI {
    converterRepository := link.NewRepository(db)
    converterService := service.NewConverterService(converterRepository)
    converterAPI := NewConverterAPI(converterService)
    return converterAPI
}

func TestGenerateDeepLink(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    mockDB, _ := dbSetup()
    api := apiSetup(mockDB)
    r := routersSetup(api)
    var jsonData = []byte(`{"weburl":"loremipsum"}`)

    r.ServeHTTP(w, httptest.NewRequest("POST", "/getDeepLink", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData)))
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code, "There is an error.")
}
```

While I get an error in this code, I don't get an error in the following case. I don't have '/' path.

```
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/", api.GenerateDeepLink()).Methods("POST")
```

Comment: I can't recreate your problem with the information you've given. The test fails because there was a 404 if I set the path in `apiRouter.HandleFunc` to `/`. I suspect you've missed an important detail while copying your code into this question, that detail is likely your anser.

Comment: I don't have "/" so 404 is my expected response but /getDeepLink gives a runtime error.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?